# Solving the system $b+c+d=4$, $ad+bc=-8$, $a+b=5$, $cd=-8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

There is a given system of equations

\begin{align} ab+c+d&=\phantom{-}4 \\ ad+bc&=-8 \\ a+b&=\phantom{-}5 \\ cd&=-8 \end{align}

I have tried to simplify it by multiplying one equation by another or adding one to another or similar. Nothing came up.

Any hints would be great! Thank you.

Comment: I mean... if you insist you could use the relationships $a+b=5$ and $cd=-8$ instead in the forms $b = 5-a$ and $d = \frac{-8}{c}$ to replace $b$'s and $d$'s as they appear elsewhere, for instance $a(5-a)+c+\frac{-8}{c} = 4$ so that it is written in two variables instead of four.  Whether or not this is "simpler" to you is open to interpretation.  There certainly isn't enough information to uniquely determine the values of $a,b,c,d,z$ from these.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry, my bad! I've just updated the second equation, there should've been d, not z

Comment: You can at least eliminate a variable... or two... or three...

Comment: Using JMoravitz's approach to reduce this system of equations, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%285-a%29+%2B+c+-+8%2Fc+%3D+4%2C+-8a%2Fc+%2B+%285-a%29c+%3D+-8) gives 6 solutions which are relatively neat ($a, c$ are all in the form $p + q\sqrt{5}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 3rd and 4th equations we find that
$$b=5-a\quad \text{ and }\quad d=-8/c. \tag{1}$$
Substituting these in the 1st and 2nd equations they become
$$ x:=(c^2+5ac-a^2c-4c-8)/c \tag{2} = 0$$ and
$$ y:=(5c^2-ac^2-8a+8c)/c = 0. \tag{3}$$
The polynomial [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $\,x\cdot c\,$ and $\,y\cdot c\,$
eliminating $\,c\,$ is
$$ 8(a-2)(a-3)(a^2-4a-1)(a^2-6a+4). \tag{4}$$
This has six roots for $\,a$. For each value of $\,a\,$
the GCD of $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ uniquely determines $\,c\,$ and the values for $\,b\,$ and
$\,d\,$ are uniquely determined from equations in $(1)$.

Of course, there is nothing unique about picking the 3rd and 4th
equations and solving for $b$ and $d$. Also, I decided to use resultants
to solve for $a$, but there are alternative ways to do so.

Answer (score 3):

> \begin{align} ab+c+d&=-4 \tag{1}\label{1} ,\\ ad+bc&=-8 \tag{2}\label{2},\\ a+b&=-5 \tag{3}\label{3},\\ cd&=-8 \tag{4}\label{4}.\end{align}

Substitution of

\begin{align}
a&=5-b
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
d&=-\frac8c
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

into \eqref{2} results in

\begin{align}
b&=\frac{40-8c}{c^2+8}
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
a &= \frac{c(5c+8)}{c^2+8}
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Next, substitution of \eqref{6}-\eqref{8}
into \eqref{1} gives an equation in $c$

\begin{align}
\frac{136c^3-32c^4+256c^2+c^6-512}{c(c^2+8)^2}
&= 4
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

which is equivalent to

\begin{align}
(c-2)(c+4)(c^2-4c-16)(c^2-2c-4)&=0
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}

with six real roots

\begin{align}
\{
2,-4,
1+\sqrt5, 1-\sqrt5, 2+2\sqrt5, 2-2\sqrt5
\}
\tag{11}\label{11}
.
\end{align}

Expressions \eqref{6}-\eqref{8} provide corresponding values of $d,b$ and $a$.